# GeoJson как тип поля для Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, миграция, geojson

Использую codeFirst и хочу загонять в бд geojson, поэтому есть таблица типа

```
 /// <summary>
/// Класс для объектов которые могут быть автоматически импортированы
/// </summary>
[Table("NamedGeoJsonObjects")]
public class NamedGeoJsonObject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Международное название сущности
    /// </summary>
    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Локализованное русское название сущности
    /// </summary>
    [Column("name_ru")]
    public string NameRu { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Geojson
    /// </summary>
    [Column("geojson")]
    public FeatureCollection GeoJson { get; set; }

}
```

При попытке создать миграцию пишет ошибку. Есть ли какой то вариант напрямую загонять в бд GeoJson (или геометрию), не используя прокладку из string
Можно конечно и так но именно этого и хотелось бы избежать

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Geojson линии
    /// </summary>
    [Column("geojson")]
    public string _GeoJson { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Geojson линии
    /// </summary>
    [NotMapped]
    public FeatureCollection GeoJson
    {
        get { return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FeatureCollection>(_GeoJson); }
        set { _GeoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value); }
    }
```

Comment: Зависит от БД, некоторые умеют работать с геометрией.

Comment: Использую postgresql, но весь смысл entity framework что бы было независимо от типа используемой бд

Comment: Я как-то пытался это реализовать на postgresql + postgis + Entity Framework, ничего из этого не вышло. Все-таки Entity Framework больше под MS SQL заточен.